# Using relational operators in subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, operators

Here is the question:

The manager asks you to retrieve the names and prices of all products that are **less than 150 Canadian Dollars or more than 300 Canadian** Dollars. Retrieve the results needed for this use case using a single query, and capture a screenshot of the query and its execution. Make sure to format the results in Canadian Dollars. The currency symbol for Canadian Dollars is the same as for U.S. Dollars, the “$” symbol

I'm using Oracle SQL developer and this is my query:

```
SELECT product_name,
to_char(price_in_us_dollars *
        (SELECT us_dollars_to_currency_ratio
         FROM Currency
         WHERE currency_name = 'Canadian Dollar'),
        'FML9999.00','NLS_CURRENCY= $')AS price_in_canadian_dollars
FROM Product
WHERE price_in_us_dollars *
      (SELECT us_dollars_to_currency_ratio
       FROM Currency
       WHERE currency_name = 'Canadian Dollar')<= 150
OR  (SELECT us_dollars_to_currency_ratio
     FROM Currency
     WHERE currency_name = 'Canadian Dollar') >= 300;
```

If I execute this, Im only getting the price that is less than $150. How do I change the format of this so that I can get products to show that is < 150 Canadian dollars or > 300 Canadian dollars, both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to multiply the exchange rate by price_in_us_dollars in the >= 300 case.

```
SELECT product_name,
to_char(price_in_us_dollars *
    (SELECT us_dollars_to_currency_ratio
     FROM Currency
     WHERE currency_name = 'Canadian Dollar'),
    'FML9999.00','NLS_CURRENCY= $')AS price_in_canadian_dollars
FROM Product
WHERE price_in_us_dollars *
  (SELECT us_dollars_to_currency_ratio
   FROM Currency
   WHERE currency_name = 'Canadian Dollar')<= 150
OR price_in_us_dollars * 
  (SELECT us_dollars_to_currency_ratio
   FROM Currency
   WHERE currency_name = 'Canadian Dollar') >= 300;
```

Comment: ah it works now! made a minor mistake...thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In the second where clause (OR...), you're missing the multiplication with price_in_use_dollars. Your larger-than comparison is against the exchange rate, which is unlikely to match :-)

Other optimisations you might consider:
 - use NOT BETWEEN so you only have to do the calculation once;
 - move the calculation to the right-hand side, so you can benefit from an index on price_in_us_dollars

Those two are mutually exclusive, though - if you move the calculation to the right you'll have to repeat it for each of the between arguments.

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect. What's wrong with `where price_in_us_dollars not between (150/<rate>) and (300/<rate>)`? The computations on the RHS are done only once, because they are independent of row. The optimization tricks are otherwise exactly right.